# Постоянный focus на button (запрет . blur)

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Есть форма регистрации в которой две кнопки ("Вариант 1" и "Вариант 2").

Одна из них должна быть обязательно выбрана, как можно сделать чтобы с последней нажатой кнопки не пропадал фокус ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не понятна связь `обязательно выбрана` и `не пропадал фокус`. может стоит при отправке формы просто проверить была выбрана одна из кнопок или нет (или сделать радиокнопки) и соответсвенно опевещать пользователя или отправлять форму

Comment: Это ведь как радио кнопка, то есть если пользователь будет заполнять форму дальше то фокус пропадет ,а должен сохранится

Comment: Это и долна быть радиокнопка. Только фокус не может быть на ней постоянно, фокус это указатель на активный элемент. Активный в момент времени всегда тот, который редактируется в этот момент времени.  Может вы немного спутали понятия,и вам просто надо передать значение выбранного варианта с формой.

Comment: вообще не понятно как можно держать фокус на кнопке...ладно это было бы input text (ну типо пока не заполнишь, не уйдешь) но кнопка...как и зачем. `пользователь будет заполнять форму дальше то фокус пропадет ,а должен сохранится`...это вообще не ясно..как? типо вы хотите заполнять инпаты, но держать фокус на кнопке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то речь идет о простой стилизации выбранного варианта. В самом примитивном случае это таки должны быть радиобатоны.

`Focus` и `Blur` здесь не при чем. `Focus` = перетабить на элемент или тыцнуть в него мышей с характерным нажатием левой кнопы. `Blur` = потерять фокус там, где он только что был. Очень по-простому

```css
label.radio{width:100px;float:left;margin:5px}
label.radio div{width:100px;height:34px;border:1px solid #000;position:absolute;top:0}
label.radio input:checked + div{background-color:#000;color:#fff}
label.radio input{opacity:0}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <div>option 1</div>
  </label>
   <label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" />
     <div>option 2</div>
  </label><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="another field" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="another field" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="another field" />
</form>
```